# AWS Objective-C Image Upload

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an older application whos image upload has begun failing, the code used it below:

dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

```
NSError * __block anError = nil;

AWSS3PutObjectRequest *por = [AWSS3PutObjectRequest new];
por.key = key;
por.bucket = bucket;
por.contentType = @"image/png";
por.contentLength = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) length]];
por.body = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
por.ACL = AWSS3ObjectCannedACLPublicRead;
[[AWSS3 defaultS3] putObject:por completionHandler:^(AWSS3PutObjectOutput * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    anError = error;
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
}];

dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

if (anError) {
    NSException *exception = [NSException exceptionWithName:@"NoahPutObjectException" reason:[anError description] userInfo:nil];
    @throw exception;
}
```

I can confirm the bucket has not changed and is in the correct region. The error I receive is this:

```
   Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" UserIn

fo={RequestId=F5B5BFDB18414371, 
    Bucket=BUCKETREDACTED, HostId=HOSTIDREDACTED, 
    Message=The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed 
using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint., Code=PermanentRedirect, 
    Endpoint=s3.amazonaws.com}
```

I have updated to using the most recent pod, but still receive this error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are using "s3.amazonaws.com" as your endpoint, and you need to instead use a region-specific endpoint address like "s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com". The correct endpoint URLs, broken down by region, can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

Comment: How exactly would I set that up? This is an old inherited code base, so I'm a bit lost in it.

Comment: Heh, you've got a leg up on me, being able to actually read that old code base. I'd start with: grep s3.amazonaws.com - basically you've got to find where that URL is either hardcoded or stored in config and change it.

Comment: Gotcha. I saw some info about that, but I thought it only applied to the non-US buckets from what I had read. Didn't realize it applied to the US ones as well.

Comment: No prob :) I'm here to be helpful to my peers. I do think the S3 endpoint change is recent, judging by comments I've read here and on GitHub.